# Modify filename of uploaded DSpace submission

Tags: dspace

I use DSpace 5.4.

Using Java, how can I change an uploaded submission's file name? I found out that [some Flyway database schema migration](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5.4/dspace-api/src/main/resources/org/dspace/storage/rdbms/sqlmigration/postgres/V5.0_2014.09.26__DS-1582_Metadata_For_All_Objects.sql#L189) changed the location of this filename.

As I don't want to run into problems with future database schema migrations, I am looking for solutions that are SQL-agnostic and instead use DSpace's domain objects.

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of a file (= a DSpace bitstream) of an archived submission, you could use the example below, given that you know the ID of the bitstream you want to update.

```
Bitstream bitstream = Bitstream.find(context, bitstreamId);
bitstream.setName("new_name");
bitstream.update();
context.commit();
```

Comment: you have the sql solution?