# DSpace 5.4 XMLUI – changing file names

Tags: java, dspace

We implemented a new step into our DSpace XMLUI workflow. This step changes the filename of the uploaded file.
We've already tried two different approaches:

- The first: 
  We followed the hints 
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952946/modify-filename-of-uploaded-dspace-submission).
  Problem is that our editors (they got their own user group) are
  obviously not authorized to do the filename change. Even when we gave
  them bitstream write permission in all choosable collections the
  authorization error still occured.

Our method looks like this:

```
private void updateFileName(DBConnection dspaceDbConnection, Context c, Item item, String fName)
            throws Exception {

        Bundle[] bundles = item.getBundles("ORIGINAL");
        for (int i = 0; i < bundles.length; i++) {
            Bitstream[] bitstreams = bundles[i].getBitstreams();
            for (int j = 0; j < bitstreams.length; j++) {
                bitstreams[j].setName(fileName);
                bitstreams[j].update();
                log.info("file name change:" + fileName);
            }
        }
        c.commit();
```

- With not succeeding in that way, we decided to do the file name change via java method directly on the database (SQL, something like UPDATE metadatavalue SET text_value = ...).
  It works out fine, apart from the fact that the index doesn't update our database changes.
  Therefor we got the following questions:
- Which is the preferred or best way to change file names in DSpace?
- Is there a feasible way to tell the index to take specific changes on the database?
  or
- Is there a way to give DSpace groups the authorization to change bitstream metadata?

Thank you for your suggestions in advance!

Comment: We found a not so cool solution to approach no. 1. It's deprecated and it seems to me like a very evil hack but it's doing its job: 
**context.setIgnoreAuthorization(true/false);**

Comment: You asked about the best way to change file names in DSpace.  I do not have a recommendation to offer.  Within DSpace, the file name is generally insignificant.  What purpose does the file rename accomplish?

Comment: We have two reasons for the renaming:
- You simply get more information about a file's content when it'named like 'ssoar-hsr-2015-2-rosol-Hauling_data_anthropocene_analogues_paleoceanography.pdf' than a simple 'file.pdf'
- And in additions to it, we have a web tracking system running which is used for usage and user's statistics research by some of our collegues. In this system it's obviously an advantage to have more informations about the files being downloaded (i.e. author, title, journal, volume, issue, year ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the DSpace 5x code, I the following is called in Item.create() when creating an item.

```
    // Call update to give the item a last modified date. OK this isn't
    // amazingly efficient but creates don't happen that often.
    context.turnOffAuthorisationSystem();
    i.update();
    context.restoreAuthSystemState();

    context.addEvent(new Event(Event.CREATE, Constants.ITEM, i.getID(), 
            null, i.getIdentifiers(context)));
```

See https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/Item.java#L179-L186

For a Bitstream, the following method Bitstream.updateLastModified() exists.

```
public void updateLastModified()
{
    //Also fire a modified event since the bitstream HAS been modified
    ourContext.addEvent(new Event(Event.MODIFY, Constants.BITSTREAM, getID(), null, getIdentifiers(ourContext)));
}
```

See https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/Bitstream.java#L728-L734

Are you attempting to get the index to discover the file name that you have assigned to the bitstream?  I do not believe that the file names are in the full text (SOLR) index.

Comment: You might be right. I also wasn't able to find them in the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of method context.turnOffAuthorisationSystem() to temporarily prevent authorization exceptions from occurring. Make sure to restore the authorization after calling context.commit() with method context.restoreAuthSystemState()!

For example:

```
private void updateFileName(DBConnection dspaceDbConnection, Context c, Item item, String fName)
            throws Exception {   
try{
        c.turnOffAuthorisationSystem()
        Bundle[] bundles = item.getBundles("ORIGINAL");
        for (int i = 0; i < bundles.length; i++) {
            Bitstream[] bitstreams = bundles[i].getBitstreams();
            for (int j = 0; j < bitstreams.length; j++) {
                bitstreams[j].setName(fileName);
                bitstreams[j].update();
                log.info("file name change:" + fileName);
            }
        }
        c.commit();
}
finally {
       c.restoreAuthSystemState()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution I was searching for! Cool!